# Incrementing a value from $1 to $1.25 million with a timed interval as a Counter

Tags: java, android, loops, textview, increment

**Visualize this**: The number starts from $0 and increments to $1.25 million and that incrementing process is shown on the UI using a timed interval between each increment (roughly 50-100 ms maybe?). I tried setting this up but sadly, the code below fails miserably.

```
double maxValue = 10;
double currentValue = 0;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //more code

        value_text = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.value_text);

        for (int i = 0; i < maxValue; i++) {
            if (currentValue != maxValue) {
                try {
                    currentValue++;
                    value_text.setText(String.valueOf(currentValue));
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

**Tricky Part:** The textview will progress from $1 to $1.25 million, which means we are going to have to change to decimals after hitting the first million. And every step is shown on the UI fast.

Do you guys have a solution to achieve this increment effect?

**EDIT:**

I'd even be happy with an existing Library (if any) to achieve this incrementing effect

Comment: First of all don't do this, `Thread.sleep(50);` on  application main UI thread. Use `TimerTask` and call `runOnUiThread` to update `TextView` or you can use `Handler`.

Comment: @user370305 : **"First of all don't do this. Thread.sleep(50);   on application main UI thread."** - Actually, better advice is to *NEVER* use `Thread.sleeep(...)` ... *EVER*. It's a nasty inelegant hack. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you'll never see the update because every operation you do on Main Thread (or Looper in android world). You should try something like this:

```
private final static long MAX_VALUE = 1000000L;
private final static int TIME = 100L;

private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private long value = 1;


private void scheduleIncrementation() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (value < MAX_VALUE) {
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(value++));
            }

            handler.postDelayed(this, TIME);
        }
    }, TIME);
}
```

And in onCreate method just call:

```
scheduleIncrementation();
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it much faster? :D I reduced the time to 1L but hey, takes forever :D

Comment: And how would I handle the million part where the numbers stick to the decimals after hitting the first million? :)

Comment: Maybe problem lays somewhere else. Is it whole code that you've posted? I have no problem doing more complicated things with drawing each 100ms and everything is fine :)

Comment: No it works fine but going from 0 to 1.25 million takes a long time. I wanted to speed it up so I changed your time 100L to 1L. Its still a bit slow. Is there a way to make it increment faster?

Comment: So increment more :) value+=5. Now you need about 2,5 hours to get to 1mln

Comment: Try `if (currentValue > 1000000) {  BigDecimal decimalValue = new BigDecimal(currentValue / 1000000);
decimalValue = decimalValue.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
value_text.setText(String.valueOf(decimalValue));
}` to get your rounding/decimal goal